# .Net MVC 4 How to get array in Model or from Form Collection on form submit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, formcollection

I am working with .net MVC 4 my problem is I have multiple input control with same name with postfix 0,1,2 like array. I want all of those values in one object or list of object. Controls in my View(Razor,.cshtml) is like below:

```
<input type="hidden" value="FirstName" name="MyListData[0]" id="MyListDataUnSelected_0_">
<input type="hidden" value="MiddleName" name="MyListData[1]" id="MyListDataUnSelected_1_">
<input type="hidden" value="LastName" name="MyListData[2]" id="MyListDataUnSelected_2_">
```

and my post method on controller is like:

```
public ActionResult Index(List<string> MyListData, FormCollection pFormCollection)
```

in from collection it gives me value of MyListData[0],MyListData[1],...
but List MyListData is null. I have one other Page in that same code is applied and in that case I get list of values in MyListData.

I also tried using string[] MyListData but still not work.

How can I get that list in model or from Form Collection.

Comment: Just a wild guess. What happens if you remove the `pFormCollection` argument from the action, and leave only `MyListData`?

Comment: Do you generate your inputs through razor helper `@Html.TextBoxFor<>`?

Comment: No, I only used <input> controls because those are created using jquery.

Comment: @DixonD if I remove pFormCollection then also MyListData is null only.

Comment: Using Firebug or similar, are you able to observe that the values are actually posted? You may also want to try installing Glimpse.

Comment: Try with just List only. Check this may help - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current solution is

```
List<string> lststr=new List<string>();
int i=0;
while(true)
{
    if(pFormCollection["MyListData[" + i + "]"]!=null)
    {
         lststr.add(pFormCollection["MyListData[" + i + "]"]);
         i++;
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

or in short

```
List<string> lststr=new List<string>();
int i=0;
while(pFormCollection["MyListData[" + i + "]"]!=null)
{

         lststr.add(pFormCollection["MyListData[" + i + "]"]);
         i++;

}
```